# Join Distinct or First

Tags: sql, inner-join, distinct

I have a table structure for SalesItems, and Sales.

SalesItems is setup something like this

```
| SaleItemID | SaleID | ProductID | ProductType |
| 1          | 1      |    1      |     1       |
| 2          | 1      |    2      |     2       |
| 3          | 1      |    15     |     1       |
| 4          | 2      |    5      |     2       |
| 5          | 3      |    1      |     1       |
| 6          | 3      |    8      |     5       |
```

And Sales is setup something like this

```
| Sale | Cash  |
| 1    | 1.00  |
| 2    | 10.00 |
| 3    | 28.50 |
```

I am trying to export a basic 'Daily History' that uses joins to spit out the information like this.

```
| Date | StoreID | Type1Sales | Type2Sales | ... | Cash Taken |
| 5/2  | 50      | 50         | 40         | ... | 39.50      |
| 5/3  | 50      | 10         | 32.50      | ... | 48.50      |
```

The issue I'm having is if I do an inner join From Sales to Sales Items, I'll end up with this.

```
| SaleItemID | SaleID | ProductID | ProductType | Sale | Cash  |
| 1          | 1      |    1      |     1       | 1    | 1.00  |
| 2          | 1      |    2      |     2       | 1    | 1.00  |
| 3          | 1      |    15     |     1       | 1    | 1.00  |
| 4          | 2      |    5      |     2       | 2    | 10.00 |
| 5          | 3      |    1      |     1       | 3    | 28.50 |
| 6          | 3      |    8      |     5       | 3    | 28.50 |
```

So if I do a SUM(Cash), then I'll end up returning $70.00, instead of the correct $39.50. I'm not the best with joins, so I've been researching outer joins and such, but none of those seem to work as it's still matching up. Is there a way to only match on the FIRST instance, and return NULL for the rest? For example, something like this

```
| SaleItemID | SaleID | ProductID | ProductType | Sale | Cash  |
| 1          | 1      |    1      |     1       | 1    | 1.00  |
| 2          | 1      |    2      |     2       | 1    | NULL  |
| 3          | 1      |    15     |     1       | 1    | NULL  |
| 4          | 2      |    5      |     2       | 2    | 10.00 |
| 5          | 3      |    1      |     1       | 3    | 28.50 |
| 6          | 3      |    8      |     5       | 3    | NULL  |
```

Or do you have any other suggestions for returning back the correct amount of Cash for each particular day?

Answer (score 0):

Use `DISTINCT(SaleID)` in your `SELECT` to return a single row for each Sale ID.

Comment: If I return a single row for each sale ID, then I'll miss out on certain sale items - for example, I would miss out on saleItems 2, 3, and 6, which throws off the totals for Type1Sales, Type2Sales, etc.

Comment: Oh sorry I missed that.  If you are stuck with this schema, I would consider two separate queries - one for summary cash per sale and another for all of the non-cash detail.  I think you should be able to get there with your original query for the detail and using `DISTINCT(SaleID)` for the cash summary.

Comment: Yeah, I'll probably get the cash details by date and then merge everything together at the end by saleDate.